# Duplicated objects copy animation

Tags: animation, linked-data

I have been designing a defense tower. I have a sphere that rotates around 360deg as it's default animation. I added two cylinders to it, one being the base for the guns, and the other being the actual gun. I plan to add another animation to as well.

The problem is that the gun cylinder(s) "Cylinder.003" are linked somehow. I used <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to duplicate the cylinder and I have 2 of the exact same cylinder. When I try to make my animation, both cylinders move, but I only want one to move at a single time. If anyone can tell me how to "unlink" these "linked" objects, it would be much appreciated. I am stuck on this project until I can unlink it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The fastest, and most efficient, way to get a good answer is to post your .blend file. (use a site like pasteall.org or similar) Also feel free to add to edit your question and add any images to illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 4):

In object mode, select one of the cylinders and press <kbd>U</kbd> to bring up the *Make Single User* menu.  Choose the *Object Animation* option. Now they will each have their own Action datablock you can animate.

Comment: Please read [this meta post](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/598/2217) about the code formatting

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me as if you failed to separate the two cylinders into separate objects when you duplicated them with <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>. Select one of the cylinders in the object "cylinder.003", and separate it from the other by pressing <kbd>P</kbd> key with the cylinder selected, and choosing from the context menu *by selecton*. This will give you another cylinder object (probably cylinder.004, but it might be different, which you can rename to "gun 2", or some such (and while on the topic, I'd advise renaming cylinder.003, too.) This will let you animate both of the two guns independently.

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand your question exactly.

If you want independent motion of visual object meshes they should be separate blender object meshes with 3 separate names in Object Mode.

I do not know how experienced you are.  I am speaking in a less experienced voice now.
Be aware of your mode ... Edit Mode to move vertices or Object mode to move a whole mesh.

In the worst case I would delete a simple model and start again if you have just a little time investment. Do not delete hours of work.

I can later have parent relationships to form a mechanical connection.
(This would be the simplest design for the time being, lets skip armatures for now)

I may not understand your question exactly.

If I modeled a simple faucet I might have 3 objects meshes.  The water spout and right cold water handle and a left hot water handle.  I can click on 3 objects and each would have a different name.  I would be in object mode in Blender.

I would not be in edit mode ... because I would he adding to the same mesh the whole time.  If you have put more than one structure in a mesh Blender can separate those items into new object meshes.  To recover from such a situation you would be in edit mode ... select the vertices you needed and choose the menus Mesh/Vertices/Separate.

If you are edit the shape of one mesh and you see the other mesh change shape as well .. you must unlink the meshes datablock.

Answer (score -1):

Select the second objects armature, place it in pose mode, open the graph editor and delete all animations for the second object.

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question.